# what does 'tar --overwrite' actually do (or not do)?

Tags: tar, overwrite

I see that Linux tar has an option --overwrite.  But overwriting seems to be the default.  Moreover, specifying tar --no-overwrite does not change this behavior as the info file seems to suggest.

So what does that option actually do?

I test it with

```
ls -l >junk
ls -l junk
tar -cf junk.tar junk
>junk
ls -l junk
tar  <option?> -xf junk.tar  # option varies, results do not
ls -l junk
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There are a few subtleties, but *in general*, here's the difference:

By default, "tar" tries to open output files with the flags `O_CREAT | O_EXCL`.  If the file exists, this will fail, after which "tar" will retry by first trying to delete the existing file and then re-opening with the same flags (i.e., creating a new file).

In contrast, with the `--overwrite` option, "tar" tries to open output files with the flags `O_CREAT | O_TRUNC`.  If the file exists, it will be truncated to zero size and overwritten.

The main implication is that "tar" by default will delete and re-create existing files, so they'll get new inode numbers.  With `--overwrite`, the inode numbers won't change:

```
$ ls -li foo
total 0
5360222 -rw-rw-r-- 1 buhr buhr 0 Jun 26 15:16 bar
$ tar -cf foo.tar foo
$ tar -xf foo.tar  # inode will change
$ ls -li foo
total 0
5360224 -rw-rw-r-- 1 buhr buhr 0 Jun 26 15:16 bar
$ tar --overwrite -xf foo.tar  # inode won't change
$ ls -li foo
total 0
5360224 -rw-rw-r-- 1 buhr buhr 0 Jun 26 15:16 bar
$
```

This also means that, for each file overwritten, "tar" by default will need three syscalls (`open`, `unlink`, `open`) while `--overwrite` will need only one (`open` with truncation).

Comment: I gather from this that the difference will be important mainly when the file has multiple links, prohibiting permissions or conceivably if the file is open elsewhere.  And that what I wanted -- preservation of any existing file -- is not possible.  I was really hoping for the equivalent of --no-clobber in cp and mv.

Comment: There's a "--skip-old-files" option that I think will do what you want.

Comment: Indeed.  Thanks for that!